# Form keydown event and textbox keydown event

Tags: vb.net

```
 Private Sub AccountType_KeyDOWN(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Return Then
            ProcessTabKey(True)
        End If
    End Sub
 Private Sub anytextbox_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Twitter.Enter, Email.Enter, PhoneNoOffice.Enter, PhoneNoHome.Enter, PhoneNoMobile.Enter, EName.Enter, AName.Enter, IDCode.Enter, ExpiryDate.Enter, BankAccount.Enter

        Dim txt As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
        stroldvalue = txt.Text

    End Sub

    Private Sub anytextbox_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Twitter.KeyDown, Email.KeyDown, PhoneNoOffice.KeyDown, PhoneNoHome.KeyDown, PhoneNoMobile.KeyDown, EName.KeyDown, AName.KeyDown, IDCode.KeyDown, ExpiryDate.KeyDown, BankAccount.KeyDown
        Dim txt As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)


        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
            If txt.Text <> stroldvalue Then
                connectunauth()
                cmd = New SqlCommand("Insert into changes values(@id,@txtname,@oldval,@newval)", Variables.UnauthCon)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", CustomerNo.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtname", txt.Name)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldval", stroldvalue)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newval", txt.Text)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                UnauthCon.Dispose()
                NOCHANGE = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

In the above code i face the following error:
On entry into one textbox, the value is saved in stroldvalue.
On pressing enter after changing in the above, the form_keydown event triggers first, which runs the anytextbox_enter event causing the stroldvalue to be overwritten by the next textbox value. and then the textbox keydown event triggers.

I tried keypress event for the form, but keypress event does not capture enter key press on combobox.
What should i do so that the keydown of form triggers after textbox keydown event.

Comment: This kind of code tends to be written by programmers that have created console mode apps before.  It just isn't very appropriate in a GUI app, the Enter key has a dedicated usage.  It adds new lines to a multiline TextBox or RichTextBox.  And operates the default button on a window.  A Windwos user already knows how to use the Tab key or mouse to change focus, avoid helping.

Comment: The user prefers enter key to the tab. Do let me know if there is a possibility to do so.

Comment: A good programmer knows when to say No.  Especially easy to do on a Q+A site ;)

Comment: i figured it out myself. I put the processtabkey(true) at the end of allcombo_keydown event and it worked!!

Comment: then you should add that as an answer, then in a few days come back and you can mark that as the official answer to your question. Then this question won't show up as unanswered any more and people like me won't waste 30 seconds of their lives reading the question, then the comments, to find that it's been solved :)